# Dimension of the poset $(\mathbb{R}^2,\ge)$

Tags: combinatorics, set-theory, order-theory

I am working on the question about the poset $(\mathbb{R}^2,\ge)$ such that $(x_1,y_1)\ge (x_2,y_2)$ iff $x_1\ge x_2, y_1\ge y_2$. I found the conclusion that the dimension of this poset is $2$, but I am not quite clear about how to prove it (The dimension of a poset is the smallest number of total orders the intersection of which gives rise to the partial order). Any thought would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in Keeley's answer, the poset does not have dimension $1$, since it is not a total order. It remains to show that it has dimension $\leq 2$, and to do this, we just need to exhibit it as the intersection of two total orders.

The lexicographic order $\leq_{\mathrm{lex}}$ is defined by $(x_1,y_1)\leq_{\mathrm{lex}} (x_2,y_2)$ if and only if $x_1 < x_2$ or ($x_1 = x_2$ and $y_1 \leq y_2$).

The reverse lexicographic order $\leq_{\mathrm{rlex}}$ is defined in the same way, but reversing the roles of $x$ and $y$: $(x_1,y_1)\leq_{\mathrm{rlex}} (x_2,y_2)$ if and only if $y_1 < y_2$ or ($y_1 = y_2$ and $x_1 \leq x_2$).

If you're not familiar with these orders, you should prove that they are total. I claim that their intersection is our ordering $\leq$.

Suppose $(x_1,y_2)\leq (x_2,y_2)$. This means $x_1\leq x_2$ and $y_1\leq y_2$. Since $x_1\leq x_2$, we have $x_1 < x_2$ or $x_1 = x_2$. In the latter case, we also have $y_1\leq y_2$. So in either case, we have $(x_1,y_1)\leq_{\mathrm{lex}} (x_2,y_2)$. The symmetric argument shows that $(x_1,y_1)\leq_{\mathrm{rlex}} (x_2,y_2)$. So ${\leq} \subseteq (\leq_{\mathrm{lex}}\cap \leq_{\mathrm{rlex}})$.

Conversely, suppose $(x_1,y_1)\leq_{\mathrm{lex}} (x_2,y_2)$ and $(x_1,y_1)\leq_{\mathrm{rlex}} (x_2,y_2)$. By the definition of $\leq_{\mathrm{lex}}$, $x_1 < x_2$ or $x_1 = x_2$, so $x_1\leq x_2$. Similarly, by definition of $\leq_{\mathrm{rlex}}$, $y_1\leq y_2$. So $(\leq_{\mathrm{lex}}\cap \leq_{\mathrm{rlex}})\subseteq {\leq}$.

Comment: Hello Alex, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks so much!

Comment: @HarukiY You're welcome. If the question is resolved, you should mark it as resolved by accepting one of the answers you've been given (click the green check mark).

Answer (score 3):

Great, so I think you and I are on the same page about why the dimension is at most $2$; we just need to show that the dimension can't be $1$. But if the dimension was $1$, then the partial order $(x_1, y_1) \geq (x_2, y_2)$ would have to be total, and we can check that it isn't. Indeed, $(1, -1)$ and $(-1, 1)$ are incomparable, and this is enough.

Comment: Hello Keeley, thanks a lot for your reply! In your explanation, you mentioned that the dimension is at most $2$ and this is where I am stuck. Is there any theorem offering this upper bound for the dimension? Thanks again.